# Crazy Android Studio memory usage

Tags: android, android-studio

This is my last resort - hope very much that someone has a clue.

I created the following custom `OnboardingGuideView`. When I add it to a layout to be displayed, the computer (Mac or Windows) starts shouting, memory reaches top and Android Studio (ver. 3.6.1) **freezes** as if there is some recursive element that's chocking the IDE somewhere.

I've tried commenting pieces of the code one by one until everything was commented. Still when I start Android Studio (without doing anything else) the "party" starts and after a minute AS is frozen.

If the `<dk.tdc.selfapp.ui.common.widgets.onboardingguide.OnboardingGuideView` component is commented, everything is ok.

My kingdom for a solution!

*View added to a layout:*

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    style="@style/RowStyle"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <dk.tdc.selfapp.ui.common.widgets.onboardingguide.OnboardingGuideView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="16dp"
        android:background="@color/errorRed10Color"
        app:descriptionPrefix="tdc_esim_finalize_guide_description"
        app:imagePrefix="esim_finalize_guide_image"
        app:titlePrefix="tdc_esim_finalize_guide_title" />

...
```

*The view:*

```
import android.content.Context
import android.text.Html
import android.util.AttributeSet
import android.view.LayoutInflater
import android.widget.FrameLayout
import android.widget.LinearLayout
import android.widget.TextView
import dk.firm.oldapp.R
import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.view_onboarding_guide.view.*

class OnboardingGuideView(context: Context, attrs: AttributeSet?, defStyleAttr: Int) : FrameLayout(context, attrs, defStyleAttr) {

    private var itemCount = 0
    private var titlePrefix = ""
    private var descriptionPrefix = ""
    private var imagePrefix = ""

    init {
        LayoutInflater.from(context)
                .inflate(R.layout.view_onboarding_guide, this, true)
        setAttributes(attrs)
    }

    private fun setAttributes(attrs: AttributeSet?) {
        attrs?.let { a ->
            val typedArray = context.obtainStyledAttributes(a,
                    R.styleable.OnboardingGuideView, 0, 0)
            titlePrefix = typedArray.getString(R.styleable.OnboardingGuideView_titlePrefix).toString()
            descriptionPrefix = typedArray.getString(R.styleable.OnboardingGuideView_descriptionPrefix).toString()
            imagePrefix = typedArray.getString(R.styleable.OnboardingGuideView_imagePrefix).toString()

            typedArray.recycle()
        }

        setup()
    }

    private fun setup() {
        itemCount = countResources(titlePrefix, "string")
        val adapter = OnboardingGuideAdapter(context, itemCount, titlePrefix, descriptionPrefix, imagePrefix)
        itemPager.adapter = adapter

        addDotsIndicator()
    }

    private fun countResources(prefix: String, type: String): Int {
        var id: Long = -1
        var count = -1

        while (id != 0L) {
            count++
            id = context.resources.getIdentifier(String.format("%s_%s", prefix, (count + 1)),
                    type, context.packageName).toLong()
        }

        return count
    }

    private fun addDotsIndicator() {
        indicatorView.removeAllViews()

        for (i in 0 until itemCount) {
            val dot = TextView(context)
            dot.text = Html.fromHtml("&#8226;")
            dot.textSize = 35F
            dot.setTextColor(resources.getColor(R.color.appColorBlueLight))

            indicatorView.addView(dot)
        }
    }
}
```

*View layout - `view_onboarding_guide`:*

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <androidx.viewpager.widget.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/itemPager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/indicatorView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:background="@color/status_text_color_red"
        android:orientation="horizontal" />
</LinearLayout>
```

*The adapter:*

```
import android.content.Context
import android.view.LayoutInflater
import android.view.View
import android.view.ViewGroup
import android.widget.ImageView
import android.widget.LinearLayout
import android.widget.TextView
import androidx.viewpager.widget.PagerAdapter
import dk.firm.oldapp.R
import dk.firm.selfapp.util.Utils

class OnboardingGuideAdapter(
        val context: Context,
        private val itemCount: Int,
        private val titlePrefix: String,
        private val descriptionPrefix: String,
        private val imagePrefix: String) : PagerAdapter() {

    override fun getCount(): Int {
        return itemCount
    }

    override fun isViewFromObject(view: View, o: Any): Boolean {
        return view == o as LinearLayout
    }

    override fun instantiateItem(container: ViewGroup, position: Int): Any {
        val view = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.view_onboarding_guide_item, container, false)
        val ordinal = position + 1

        // Instantiate views
        val titleView = view.findViewById<TextView>(R.id.onBoardingItemTitle)
        val descriptionView = view.findViewById<TextView>(R.id.onBoardingItemDescription)
        val imageView = view.findViewById<ImageView>(R.id.onBoardingItemImage)

        // Create resource names
        val title = String.format("%s_%s", titlePrefix, ordinal)
        val description = String.format("%s_%s", descriptionPrefix, ordinal)
        val image = String.format("%s_%s", imagePrefix, ordinal)

        // Populate views
        titleView.text = Utils.getStringFromResId(context.resources.getIdentifier(title, "string", context.packageName))
        descriptionView.text = Utils.getStringFromResId(context.resources.getIdentifier(description, "string", context.packageName))
        imageView.setImageResource(context.resources.getIdentifier(image, "drawable", context.packageName))

        container.addView(view)

        return view
    }

    override fun destroyItem(container: ViewGroup, position: Int, o: Any) {
        container.removeView(o as LinearLayout)
    }
}
```

*The item layout - `view_onboarding_guide_item`:*

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatTextView
        android:id="@+id/onBoardingItemTitle"
        style="@style/TextAppearance.Subtitle1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatTextView
        android:id="@+id/onBoardingItemDescription"
        style="@style/TextAppearance.Body1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp" />

    <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatImageView
        android:id="@+id/onBoardingItemImage"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After this problem persisting outside of Windows and reproduced on Mac and Linux, a colleague of mine took the chance to dig into it and he came up with this:

```
init {
    LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.view_onboarding_guide, this, true)
    if (!isInEditMode) // <- this :-(
        setAttributes(attrs)
}
```

.. which solved the problem. This looks totally crazy to me and stinks heavily of a bug in AS.

I've built countless custom views and never encountered such a problem which demanded the use of `isInEditMode` in the view.

I'll certainly keep this in mind for the future, but if anyone can explain why this helps and why this isn't a bug, then I'll appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

Android Studio is known to hog memory, a trait inherited from the IntelliJ IDE it is derived from. You can see how much memory AS is using and has available to it in the lower-right-hand corner of the screen:

[image: Memory usage indicator and surrounding icons]

(This may not display all the time, it is a setting that can be turned in the application settings if it isn't shown)

Firstly, you can tell AS to clear out memory it isn't using by clicking on this readout!

Secondly, AS freezing typically indicates that it needs a bit more than is allotted. Fortunately, you can increase the limit yourself. [As shown by ProAndroidDev](https://proandroiddev.com/improve-your-experience-on-android-studio-c8aeb25e80f), you can edit the VM options for studio:

Go to `Help > Edit Custom VM Options` and edit the following two attributes:

`Xmx`: Default is `1280m`, PAD recommends changing this to `4096m`

`XX:MaxPermSize`: Default is `350m`, PAD recommends changing this to `1024m`

For details on what these (and other) values are, [check out this article on the custom VM options and speeding up Android Studio](https://medium.com/@haydar_ai/easy-ways-to-speed-up-android-studio-2fafe1179b43).

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, but I've already been through these steps of adjusting heap size and the likes. Problem still exists.

Comment: Ah, well. I'mg going to leave the answer up for others who find your question, but I hope someone has a better answer for your specific case!